# AWS CloudFrontのデータ送信(OUT)の料金の見方

Tags: aws, aws-cloudwatch

現状、AWSから受け取った請求書は以下のような内容になっていました。
リージョンは東京で、実数はダミーです。

```
Bandwidth USD xx.xx
$0.060 per GB - All data transfer out to Origin (Japan) 5.123 GB USD x.xx
$0.070 per GB - next 4 PB / month data transfer out 4.234 GB USD x.xx
$0.080 per GB - next 524 TB / month data transfer out 3.345 GB USD x.xx
$0.084 per GB - next 350 TB / month data transfer out 2.456 GB USD x.xx
$0.086 per GB - next 100 TB / month data transfer out 1.567 GB USD x.xx
```

東京リージョンのOUTは「最初の100TBまでは1GBあたり0.086ドル」という値段設定になっているはずですが
一番下の行はデータ転送量が1.567GB しか使われていません。

ダミーの数字ではありますが、この場合だと合計で100TBにも満たないので
全ての合計転送量が0.086ドル/GB で請求されるものではないのでしょうか？

なぜ4PB(0.070ドル/GB)やそれ以上(0.060ドル/GB)の料金が発生しているのでしょうか？

Comment: サポートに聞けば詳しく説明してもらえます。請求に関わることですのでサポート契約が無くても対応してもらえます。

Comment: おそらく数字がダミーだからだと思うのですが、100 TB の部分が埋まっていないのに 350 TB の部分が埋まり始めているのは何かおかしそうなので、やはりサポートに聞くのが良さそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。一旦了解しました。